# How to add Vue CLI + Webpack to an existing LAMP backend?

Tags: php, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I have an existing server with a PHP backend on apache for a "local wikipedia". I'm having trouble integrating Vue + Webpack with my backend. I've changed the `build.index` path in `config/index.js` so I can try to verify that it's building to a location I can reference when I load my web app from wiki's "builder". I'm fairly certain I need to use `dev.proxyTable` to configure the routing but I'm not sure how I should do that. Wiki uses `index.php` and `api.php` for essentially everything. Should I be proxying for those endpoints?

Comment: I have the same question... sucks no one has answered this :/